# camera ISO, Shutter Speed in flutter

Tags: flutter, plugins, camera

I am using the camera plugin: ^0.9.4+14   for camera in flutter, but I want to explore more advance features of camera for IOS and android both. So please help me out for this.I am not able to use the [camera] ISO, Shutter Speed etc like features.

Comment: The official camera plugin doesn't seem to support it yet and the flutter manual camera plugin is a dead end.
https://github.com/afonsocraposo/manual_camera/issues/3

Did you find any other leads or solutions?